# Jquery multiple modal dialogs by classname?

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog

How can I create multiple modal dialogs by classname (basically the same dialogs but have a different code black attached).

One I launch a modal dialog I cannot reference the dialog anymore because jQuery will move it to the bottom of the document so something like..

```
$(this).find('.dialog').dialog('open');
```

Would not work anymore.

Comment: @mech7 i've read your reply to my answer but i don't really understand what you mean when you say 'it moves the html to the bottom'.  If you could explain that, or the question, a little more then hopefully we can help you.

Comment: Well after you open a modal dialog.. from lets say:

<div class=""portlet">
 <div class="modal">Hello</div>
</div>

The div modal will be moved all the way to the bottom of the DOM.. just above the body tag..

So I cannot find it anymore by using $(.portlet).find('modal')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this question correctly, you have multiple dialogs that have the same class name and you want to be able to show them all at different times?

If this is the case then you can simply add a second class name to the class attribute which uniquely identifies the dialogs but maintains the first class giving you its look and feel.

class='dialog OpenFileDialog' and then maybe class='dialog SavePictureDialog''

So then in code you reference them by the second class name `$(this).find('.OpenFileDialog').dialog('open');`

Does this help?

Comment: Yes you are right this is what I want to do.. maybe I was not really clear but this reference to a portlet.. where there could be multiple instances in the same page..

I guess I can count every modal dialog and give it a new idea, but it's not really a clean solution I rather have a way where it not moves the html for the modal dialog. I was hoping Jq UI supported this but maybe i am better of writing my own..